# laravel hasone not able to get the result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-one

i'm trying to get the role of a user either is it admin or client with hasOne relationship but when i'm trying to get the details and doing dd im getting the exists as false can anyone help me out please

[this is the result when im using dd in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIjxE.png)

```
//migration for user
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//migration for role

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->enum('role',['Club Manager','Admin','Mc']);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//UserModel

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use \App\Role;

 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
 use Notifiable;


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function Role(){
    return null;
}
public function getrole(){
    $role=$this->hasMany('App\Role');

    return $role;
}
public function getuserRole(){
    return Role::where('user_id',$this->id)->first();
}
} 
//Controller
public function getrole(){
dd(Auth::user()->getrole());
 }
```

Comment: Show your controller or view code how you call this function

Comment: @MaheshBhattarai i have edited the post by adding controller as suggested im trying to learn laracel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the relationship as a property, not as a method:

```php
Auth::user()->getrole;
```